# How to fix a poorly stitched panorama

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, panorama

I was going through my photos from a few years ago and found a lovely panorama of some scenery (forest + sky) 3 pictures wide. I'd love to fix it up to be print-quality but really have no idea how to go about doing that.
As far as I can tell, the only file I have for it is a badly stitched panorama similar to the one found here: http://thephorce.net/me/pics/grandcanyon14/gc_panorama.jpg

The problem is its actually a slight bit blurry where the photos join. I'll try to remember to link/upload the actual image when I get home.

I have the ability to use photoshop to fix it but I'm not terribly *good* at fiddling with things in photoshop, so any advice would be super useful it it links to a tutorial or includes the name of the technique so I can google how to actually do it :)

Answer (score 7):

This is just my opinion, but there's no way to "fix" stitching errors other than to re-stitch the panorama, and if you don't have the original images, but just the resultant panorama, then there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If some of the image(s) are blurry (i.e. out of focus or motion blur), there isn't any amount of post production work that is going to fix that.

If the images were shot with different settings that impacted the exposure, it is likely that you can do something about it with relative ease, although you aren't exactly guaranteed perfect results either.

Comment: Its where the camera stitched the photos together that is a bit blurry/odd. The photos themselves are fine

Comment: @SnyperBunny Gotcha. Can you post the images and attempt?

Comment: I can post it later today. I totally forgot about it last night - its on my home computer.

Answer (score -1):

I know I am quite late at answering this, but Photoshop now does have an automerge function which can stitch images as you like.
As you had mentioned in the comments you just have issue with the camera stitched images and the individual images are fine. The process to do so in Photoshop is,

1. Open all photos in Photoshop as either jpg or psd, but I'll suggest to keep them as JPEG or jgp and not PSD because then you will use more storage
2. Go to file, automate, and select auromerge.
3. Wizard box opens, add all open files to the wizard files. Select the settings you want.
4. Wait for it to process. Fyi: if the images are individually very high in size and pixels, it will take time depending on the processing capacity of the computer. So just wait, have a coffee.
5. Check the resultant merged file. If not proper or as required then try to club/group them according to the content of the images. Because that's what Photoshop does. And repeat the same set of tasks with the groups you made. Then merge the final merged file from groups!

I hope this does help someone.

Edit:
I did read the post again, yes you do not have the original photos of the panorama, but maybe try this (would be only feasible and logical if you don't have many blurred parts in the image).
1. Crop the original stiched photos in Photoshop in pieces with edges being the parts where you feel highest distortion or blur.
2. Fix these images using selection tools, transform tool and make a perspective transform of the blurred parts
3. If you are somewhat satisfied with this, go ahead and use auromerge from Photoshop.

This may to some extent reduce the visible distortion/blur but if you wish to get a very high quality print or submition this may not work 100%.

Comment: I don't think this will help the particular case, because there are no non-stitched originals.

Comment: Yes I did read the post again. Maybe there is a way around not sure if that would work. Still editing my original answer.